# How to add/remove class to the clicked parent link in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have three Links , on click of the link , how can i add a class to the clicked link ?

The class must be added to clicked one's parent that is  nav-item start

This is my code

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope)
{

// The class must be added to clicked one's parent that is  nav-item start

        $scope.callOne = function()
        {
                alert('one');
        }
        $scope.callTwo = function()
        {
                alert('two');
        }
        $scope.callThree = function()
        {
                alert('three');
        }
});
```

My Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/448/

Could you please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass `$event` via the `ng-click` method and then parse to desired parent.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope)
{
        $scope.callOne = function(evt)
        {      
        parentElement(evt);
        }
        $scope.callTwo = function(evt)
        {
                parentElement(evt);
        }
        $scope.callThree = function(evt)
        {
                parentElement(evt);
        }
        
        var element;
        function parentElement(evt){
       
        if(element!=undefined && element.classList.contains('red')){
          element.classList.remove('red');
        }
        
        if(evt.target.classList.contains('nav-item')){
         element = evt.target;
        }else if(evt.target.parentNode.classList.contains('nav-item')){
        element = evt.target.parentNode;
        }else if(evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains('nav-item')){
        element = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        }
        
        element.classList.add('red')
      
        return element;
        }
});
```

```css
.red
{
      background-color: #03A9F4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed " data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" style="padding-top: 20px">
         <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
         
         <!-- END SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
         <li class="nav-item start ">
            <a  ng-click="callOne($event)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
            <span class="title">ONE</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item start ">
            <a  ng-click="callTwo($event)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
            <span class="title">TWO</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item start ">
            <a  ng-click="callThree($event)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
            <span class="title">THree</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
       
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not do it this way, this goes against all angular's practices. Don't ever use elements in angular controllers, but only logic. The templates should then use the controller's variables to output the correct html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an `ng-repeat` in combination with `ng-class`:

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item start" 
    ng-repeat="link in links" 
    ng-class="{ active: activeLink === link.id }">
    <a ng-click="linkClicked(link)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
      <span class="title">{{ link.title }}</span>
      <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.links = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "ONE"
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "TWO"
}, {
    id: 3,
    title: "THREE"
}];

$scope.linkClicked = function(link) {
    $scope.activeLink = link.id;
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/449/

If you cannot make it dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: activeLink === 1}">
    <a ng-click="activeLink = 1">..</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{ active: activeLink === 2}">
    <a ng-click="activeLink = 2">..</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{ active: activeLink === 3}">
    <a ng-click="activeLink = 3">..</a>
</li>
```